# Which Classes are Cached in second level cache in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, second-level-cache

Is there a way for me to find out which Classes (i.e instance of which different types )  are cached in hibernate second level cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second level cache doesn't cache *instances* of entities, it caches a "dehydrated" version of entities. This is well explained in this [blog post](https://acupof.blogspot.com/2008/01/background-hibernate-comes-with-three.html):

> ### The 2nd level cache
>
> The hibernate cache does not store
> instances of an entity - instead
> Hibernate uses something called
> dehydrated state. A dehydrated state
> can be thought of as a deserialized
> entity where the dehydrated state is
> like an array of strings, integers etc
> and the id of the entity is the
> pointer to the dehydrated entity.
> Conceptually you can think of it as a
> Map which contains the id as key and
> an array as value. Or something like
> below for a cache region:
>
> ```
> { id -> { atribute1, attribute2, attribute3 } }
> { 1 -> { "a name", 20, null } }
> { 2 -> { "another name", 30, 4 } }
> ```
>
> If the entity holds a collection of
> other entities then the other entity
> also needs to be cached. In this case
> it could look something like:
>
> ```
> { id -> { atribute1, attribute2, attribute3, Set{item1..n} } }
> { 1 -> { "a name", 20, null, {1,2,5} } }
> { 2 -> { "another name", 30, 4, {4,8} } }
> ```

Depending on the L2 cache provider you're using, you might get some console to monitor/browser the cache but, still, you won't see "instances".

#### Resources

- [Hibernate Caches](https://acupof.blogspot.com/2008/01/background-hibernate-comes-with-three.html)
- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](https://web.archive.org/web/20190719063218/https://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)
- [Understanding Caching in Hibernate – Part Three : The Second Level Cache](https://www.dynatrace.com/news/blog/)