# Cache Event Listeners - Retrieving Element

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I have implemented Hibernate 2nd Level using EhCache and register the cache event listeners using the instruction

here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-event-listeners

The CacheEventListenerFactory and CacheEventListener works but may I know how to retrieve out my Entity from the element?

I have try

```
public void notifyElementPut(final Ehcache cache, final Element element) throws CacheException{
     ABEEntity entity =  (ABCEntity)element.getObjectValue(); // throws ClassCastException

}
```

It keeps throwing class cast exception. May I know is the ObjectValue wrapped? I believe is an array but I can't find any information on it.

Can someone kindly provide the answer and documentation?

The documentation is more important than the answer ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't get access to your entity object by doing this since Hibernate 2nd lvl caching does not store the entity but something called dehydrated state.

See this [Which Classes are Cached in second level cache in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715301/which-classes-are-cached-in-second-level-cache-in-hibernate) for further details.